# ASP.NET 2.0 application never loads

Tags: asp.net

I have an application that runs perfectly fine locally using the VS 2010 application server, however, when I deploy to our web app machine startup just spins and spins and never loads.  We have other apps on this same machine that load just fine (this is a debug deployment of same app in product).

I have been spinning my wheels on this for days and I am at a loss as the problem could be.

Here is what I did

1. Create a new directory (same level as other apps)
2. Copied over our existing test (www.domain/test/) and it works fine
3. Build and publish new debug app (www.domain/test/) and it just spins trying to load first form.

I know the diretory is "working" as the 'test' application I put there works fine.

Comment: @Mike this can be from many reasons that have to do with the dlls, or the redirection on the urls, or with wrong configure of web.config, or with wrong version of asp.net that runs your web or or... can you see the Event Viewer for asp.net errors ?

Comment: What version of Visual Studio are you using? Also, is this a web site, or a web application project?

Comment: Verify that you have CustomErrors Off, and check event viewer for ASP.NET errors.  Does your app do anything on page load like connect to a SQL server?  It could be timing out there.  You might want to attach remote debugger to it and break to see what code is executing.

Comment: There are some 15 pages to this website and 13 of the 15 pages work correctly.  I have added various debug statements but the "freeze" occurs before the page is loaded so far as I can tell.  It is puzzling that some of the app works.

Comment: What browser are you using? Firefox and Chrome will let you know if the application is caught in an infinite redirect loop. IE won't

Comment: I am testing with IE8, but I have access to Firefox on dev machine as well.  How can i see if it is in a loop (that would be great to find)

Comment: Further information, if I let this "loading" run too long, it will eventually kill IIS (Service Unavailable - Application Pool Error) and I need to restart the IIS service.

Comment: @MikeErickson: Were you able to resolve this? How?

Answer (score 0):

If it's killing the App pool, you might get something in the event log. Fiddler (www.fiddlertool.com) is great http debug tool which let you see if you're in a redirect loop. Also Firefox shows a more meaningful error, something about exceeding the max redirect count.

It does sound like something is looping, but not quick enough to cause a stack overflow, which is odd, because you'd expect it to fail every time.

Simon

Comment: I have tried Fiddler, I have tride Trace="true" and nothing yields any data, etc.  The page never loads and these tools arent even triggered (yet) So far as I can tell, it is even BEFORE this.  What is very strange is that on some records, the page loads just fine but on others it always dies.   AND this is not a database issue so far as I can tell as it is BEFORE ANY code runs.

Comment: The only thing that the Event Viewer tells me is: Faulting application w3wp.exe, version 6.0.3790.3959, stamp 45d6968e, faulting module kernel32.dll, version 5.2.3790.4480, stamp 49c51f0a, debug? 0, fault address 0x0000bef7.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the ability to remote desktop into the machine?  If so try running [process explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653) and look at the process details for the worker process that is giving you issues.  Definitely look at the TCP connections being created.  If your processor is pegged at 100%, and memory usage is rising then you probably have an endless loop running.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like it's more related to IIS than ASP.NET.  What about the identity that the website is running under?  Is it possible that the user the site's running under a bad user, or maybe the password needs to be re-entered?

Answer (score 0):

I did a quick Bing search

There are a lot of postings regarding the error message you described above.  Most if not all point to code in your app that is crashing.  I know I had a similar problem when I used an automated/threaded daemon utility in my web application.  Make sure your code is not bringing down the server, sometimes the VS2010 web server is a little more foregiving than an actual IIS deployment.

If that doesn't work try running a Remote Debugging Session to try and catch any errors being thrown but not handled.

Lastly you could try to setup a new local IIS server to see if you have the same problems.  [Scott Gu has a nice article about using IIS Express to do this](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/06/28/introducing-iis-express.aspx).